# g' strictly increasing different proof

Tags: analysis

Good morning,

We want to show that a function g(x) is **strictly** increasing on interval I **if and only if:**
a)its derivative is greater than **or equal to** zero on I: g'(x)>=0
**b)the set on which g'(x)=0 doesn't contain any intervals.**

I only know to prove: 
g(x) is strictly increasing <=> Its derivative is **strictly greater** than 0:  g'(x)> 0 using the mean value theorem.

How can I prove it now in the way asked? That its derivative has to only be  greater or equal to zero, and  **b)the set on which g'(x)=0 doesn't contain any intervals.**?

Thank you,

Comment: Think of a function like $x^3$.  It is strictly increasing but it is not true that it's derivative is strictly greater than $0$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's true that:

1. if $g'(x)>0 \implies$ $g(x)$ is strictly increasing but the converse
   is not true

And it's also true that:

2. if $g'(x\geq0$ and the set on which $g'(x)=0$ doesn't contain any
   intervals then $g(x)$ is strictly increasing

$g(x)=x^3$ is a good example for both the statements

For the proof of the first statement you can use MVT.

For the **proof of the second statement** it is sufficient to note that since $g'(x)\geq 0 \implies$ $g(x)$ must be increasing; if it was not stricly increasing it should exist an interval for which $g'(x)=0$ but it is not the case then **g(x) is strictly increasing**.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry, I had no connection access thus why late reply. How about the other way? If we suppose the function is strictly increasing, we have by the MVT that g'>=0. How about the second part, how can we prove that the set on which g'(x)=0 doesn't contain any intervals.?

Comment: If you suppose that $g'(x)\geq0$ then $g$ is increasing. Now if $g$ is not strictly increasing then exists an interval in which g'(x)=0 but it can't be for hypotesis (contradiction), thus $g(x)$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: Yes, that I understood. I am talking about the direct way of the implication:

Comment: I want to prove that g is strictly increasing implies that:  a) g'>=0 AND  b) the set on which g'(x)=0 doesn't contain any intervals.  It is easy to prove a). How about b)?

Comment: It's not true in general, you may have function strictly increasing but not differentiable.

Comment: We are given that the function is differentiable on I.

Comment: If there exists an interval for which g'(x)=0 then g is constant in that interval but that is a contradiction with the hypotesis.

Answer (score 0):

I think its true. Let me try a proof for $g:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$:

Let $g$ be strictly increasing. Then $g'\geq 0$. Now pick an $x\in I$ such that $g'(x)=0$ and an $\varepsilon>0$. Now assume for every $y\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ you have $g'(y)=0$. Hence $g$ is constant on that subinterval, a contradiction.

For the converse part: If $g'\geq 0$, $g$ is monotonically increasing (but not yet strictly). Assume you can find $x<y$ with $g(x)=g(y)$. Hence $g$ has to be constant on $[x,y]$, therefore $g'=0$ on $[x,y]$, a contradiction.

Comment: It's true that: if $g'(x\geq0$ and the set on which $g'(x)=0$ doesn't contain any intervals $\implies$ $g(x)$ is strictly increasing but not the converse.

Comment: Hello, can you please explain to me what is Bε(x)?

Comment: $B_\varepsilon(x)=(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$