# Domain of k in $f(x)=x^3+kx^2+5x+4\sin^2x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question says:

Let $f(x)=x^3+kx^2+5x+4\sin^2x$ be an increasing function on $x \in R$. Then domain of k is?

This is What I tried:

I tried differentiating the expression but $f'(x)$ didn't turn out to be a quadratic(as it has that $\sin2x$ term)
$$f'(x)=3x^2+2kx+5+4\sin2x>0$$

So how else am I supposed to solve this question?

Comment: @Netchaiev https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+sin%5Bx%5D%5E2

Comment: @Netchaiev I know its $2\sin x \cos x$ but aren't they both the same??

Comment: yes you are both right, my bad :) (deleting the first comment)

Comment: @Netchaiev not a big deal..its ok

Comment: @Netchaiev It's alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set up of the problem is completely right with only one remark: you can set $$f'(x)\ge0$$ to have $f(x)$ increasing and maybe also strictly increasing since the the set on which $f'(x)=0$ for "regular functions" like the given doesn't contain any intervals.

You can refer also to this [other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2571704/505767) for a detailed comment on this latter fact.

For a first estimation of the range note that for

$$3x^2+2kx+5\ge4$$

the condition is satisfy, thus from here we can find a first range for $k\in[-\sqrt 3,\sqrt 3]$, indeed

$$3x^2+2kx+1\ge0 \iff \Delta=4k^2-12\le 0$$

To improve the result we could try to find the minimum of $f'(x)$ and set it to $0$, that is

$$f''(x)=6x+2k+8\cos2x=0 \implies x=x_k$$

and

$$f'(x_k)=0$$

Comment: I thought about that but won't it be wrong because we are fixing the value of x so that sin2x attains maxima or minima??

Comment: It is a first good estimation since $4\sin2x\ge -4$ if $3x^2+2kx+5\ge4$ we are sure that $f'(x)\ge 0$. .

Comment: sorry...didn't really get it...how does that answer my question??

Comment: @Carrick No it doesn't answer it is only an hint, I'm thinking about it to improve the estimation and some one else will give other answers, wait to accept as solved, but you can upvote if you think it was useful to you.

Comment: by question I didn't mean the actual queston..I was talking about what I just asked in the comments(fixing the value of x thing) and your hint is correct..it matches with the actual answer

Comment: @Carrick Yes of course the set up for the problem is absolutely correct, while the problem itself is not trivial to be solved.

Comment: ohh...okay...thank you very much btw

Comment: @Carrick I've added only a  remark on $f'(x)\ge 0$ and I'm going to add some other comment on this concept.

Answer (score 0):

From $f '(x)=3x^2+2kx+5+4\sin2x$, try to solve $f'(x)=0$, so 
$$k=\frac{-3x^2-5-4\sin2x}{2x}$$
If you can't solve $f'(x)=0$, then $f(x)$ is increasing, so the domain of $k$ is everything outside the range of that function.